# Searching Dictionary value of Object Book with substring

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a library GUI with a few buttons (add book, remove book, search etc.) which uses a Dictionary. The Book constructor has 2 parameters, ISBN and title. I have 2 textboxes which ask the user for the ISBN and the title before adding. I'm using `library[ISBNtext.Text] = new Book(ISBNtext.Text, TITLEtext.Text);` to create new Books and add them to the dictionary. I need the search button to search the books in the dictionary either by ISBN or by title using a substring (searching for "cat" would return "How to look after your cat").

My code is as follows:

```cs
private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    libraryList.Items.Clear();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Book> book in library)
    {
        if (book.Key.Contains(ISBNtext.Text) || book.Value.Title.Contains(TITLEtext.Text))
        {
            libraryList.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} = {1}", book.Key, book.Value.Title));
        }
    }

    ISBNtext.Clear();
    TITLEtext.Clear();
}
```

If I add a few simple books (ISBN: 1 - TITLE: 1, ISBN: 2 - TITLE: 2, ISBN: 3 - TITLE: 3 etc.) and do a search for 1 it just displays every book that has been added instead of just the one(s) I searched for.

I should also mention that this is for school, so I'm not sure I can use any libraries or anything.

Comment: Can ISBN also be a partial match?  The purpose of a Dictionary is that the (full) key gives a quick lookup for the the object.  You are not utilising this at all and instead doing a brute force search of the items.  You might as well be using a List.

Comment: After I altered it based on Akshey's answer I think it returns partial ISBN matches as well.  Also this is part of a work sheet that explicitly mentions to use a Dictionary.

Comment: preferably for ISBN you should use == operator instead of contains().

Comment: I agree, used separate if statements and changed the ISBN check to == instead of contains() and everything works as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to check if `ISBNtext.Text` or `TITLEtext.Text` is empty. If either of them is empty `contains()` will return `true`. That is the reason you are getting an incorrect result. add condition in if clause as below:-

```
if ((book.Key.Contains(ISBNtext.Text) && book.Key != string.Empty) || (book.Value.Title.Contains(TITLEtext.Text) && book.Value.Title != string.Empty) )
        {
            libraryList.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} = {1}", book.Key, book.Value.Title));
        }
```

Comment: Would it be better to use two separate if statements if I don't want to force the user to enter both ISBN and title if they only want to search for one of them?

Comment: yes you can do that too. or you could add a condition in the if clause to check for empty textboxes as given in my modified answer

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answers may have solved the problem in your code but if you're asked to use a Dictionary you should consider if you should be making the most of the methods it provides.

The purpose of a Dictionary is that the key provides a quick lookup for the stored object which saves time compared to a full search of a list.

I've broken down your search into two separate searches below as an example.  The first one matches a complete ISBN number (if provided) and uses the key of the dictionary as a quick lookup.  The second is the slower title search which you can use the code you already have (just remove the ISBN part of it).

```
private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    libraryList.Items.Clear();

    // ISBN number search
    var isbnNo = ISBNtext.Text;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(isbnNo)){
      if (library.ContainsKey(isbnNo)){
        var book = library[isbnNo];
        libraryList.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} = {1}", book.ISBNNo, book.Title));
      }
    }

    // Title search
    var titleText = TITLEtext.Text;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(titleText)){
      foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Book> book in library)
      {
          // search based on title like your existing code
      }
    }

    ISBNtext.Clear();
    TITLEtext.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add check of empty inputs:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Book> book in library)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ISBNtext.Text) && book.Key.Contains(ISBNtext.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TITLEtext.Text) && book.Value.Title.Contains(TITLEtext.Text))
        {
            libraryList.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} = {1}", book.Key, book.Value.Title));
        }
    }
```